# One or more domain names have failed validation due to a Certificate Authority Authentication (CAA) error - Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-certificate-manager

i cannot get a certificate using AWS Certificate Manager, i have my domain in Route 53 with the following records
[image]
i receive the email to confirm the request and i approve it i get the error "One or more domain names have failed validation due to a Certificate Authority Authentication (CAA) error"
[image]
[image]

i want to get the certificate to use it in cloudfront

Answer (score 0):

Update:
i solved the issue adding a CAA record with: issue 0 "amazon.com" in my hosted zone, i had to wait 1 minute then create another certificate request (i used email method) and i worked.